# Configuring page viewer to refresh SharePoint page after clicking it

Tags: page-viewer-web-part, refresh

I have a set of items displayed in page viewer web parts that are from an external site. In order for them to display login credentials for external site are needed. I put the login page as the first web part (page viewer) on the sharepoint library. how do I make it so that after login is completed the page refreshes automatically to now display the other web parts? 
 [image: example]

Answer (score 1):

The Page Viewer webpart actually creates an < iframe >-html-object.
The problem is that due to the security risks caused by iframes in the past every browser nowadays sandboxes the iframe. The iframe has no access to the DOM of the parent-page, so you can't access the other iframes (Page Viewer webparts).
More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx